# How can I copy files in PHP with special unicode characters?

Tags: php, unicode, copy, urldecode

I have to copy some pdf files from a web to the file path of the new version of the web. That pdf files are linked by html `a` in content.

So what I'm doing is getting all links to pdf with a *regex*, copying them to a new path and changing the link to the new path. But I have problems with some files with special characters. For example:

```
$original_path = '/path/Dossier%20Nicola%CC%81s%20Combarro_GAL_CAST.pdf'
$decoded_path = urldecode($oiginal_path);
copy($decoded_path, $new_path);
```

And it shows the following error:

`File '/path/Dossier Nicola´s Combarro_GAL_CAST.pdf' could not be copied because it does not exist.`

Of course it exists but with the name: `/path/Dossier Nicolás Combarro_GAL_CAST.pdf`. I can open it with a pdf reader, and also I can open it via web browser when I click in the link.

It seems that PHP decoded `a%CC%81` as `a´` but Windows decoded it as `á`. How can copy this file properly?

I'm running PHP on a VM with Debian, but files are in a shared folder (NFS) with Windows 10 (NTFS).

Comment: What OS are you using to host your PHP? What is the character encoding of your file system?

Comment: @KoalaYeung I'm running PHP on a VM with Debian, but files are in a shared folder (NFS) with Windows 10 (NTFS).

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses the Windows-1252 character set for file names and paths. If you are working with UTF-8, you will need to convert the file name.

Example:

```
$utf8FileName = 'René.txt';
$windowFileName = mb_convert_encoding($utf8FileName,'Windows-1252','UTF8');

//Filesystem Win10
$content = file_get_contents($windowFileName);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm having the same result _Rene´.txt_